# What type of UI component is this?

Tags: ios, uikit

I see this type of action sheet on iOS devices using the Google Drive application.
I want to know if it is already supported on iOS SDK or if it is a custom UI?
If it is already a standard component, what's name of it?

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, got it. It's only for iOS 8 and later. It's named [UIDocumentPickerExtensionViewController](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIDocumentPickerExtensionViewController_Class/index.html).

Answer (score 0):

It was called UIActionSheet before iOS8 and after you can find this UI component under the UIAlerController. You can use this component to make some UI like this but development target should be more that iOS8.

You can check [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIAlertController_class/) for documentation.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not aware of any custom components, but it looks to me like a standard `UIAlertController` with a `ActionSheet` style. As the alert controller extends `UIViewController`, you may add subviews to it.

The screenshots indicate that they added a `UITableView` as a subview to the alert controller: [image]